# Makefile behavior in Cygwin

Tags: c, unix, makefile, cygwin

when i try to do compile `Keys.c` program using `Makefile` in `Cygwin` on Windows 7 64bit

it should compile it as following

```
gcc -g -Wall -ansi -c keys.c
```

but i get the following

```
`cc     keys.c   -o keys`  not `gcc -g -Wall -ansi -c keys.c`
```

the make file is as follow

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -ansi

keys:   keys.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c keys.c
```

Comment: Is your file `keys.c` or `Keys.c`? I don't know whether cygwin (or make in cygwin) is case-insensitive or not.

Comment: Note that your compile line is wrong: you are trying to build an executable so you should not use `-c`.  The `-c` flag tells the compiler to compile to an object file but don't link.

Answer (score 1):

Remove -c before `keys.c` whats happening here is when you give

`$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c keys.c`

then only the object file `keys.o` is created. Since the rule for making the final target is not written the makefile will use the implicit rule to create the target.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -ansi

keys:   keys.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) keys.c
```